# how to download and save video using nodejs

Tags: node.js

i want to download video from tiktok

using **nodejs** and **tiktok-scraper-without-watermark** package

but when the mp4 file downloaded wont open
is there is any more work

`http://localhost:7780/tik?title=test&url=https://www.tiktok.com/@youneszarou/video/6942436555692805381`

my attempt is

```
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const tiktok = require("tiktok-scraper-without-watermark");
const pool = require("../config/db");

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { title, url } = req.query;
    const path = process.cwd() + `/videos/${title}.mp4`;
    const tik = await tiktok.tiktokdownload(url);
    //console.log("tik", tik);

    const requ = https.get(tik.nowm, (response) => {
      const file = fs.createWriteStream(path);
      response.pipe(file);
      file.on("error", function (err) {
        console.log("err", err);
      });
      file.on("finish", function () {
        file.close();
        console.log("done");
      });
    });

    requ.on("err", (error) => {
      console.log("error", error);
    });

    res.status(200).json(tik);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    res.status(401).json(error);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

the result of tiktok package is

```
{
nowm: "https://ttdownloader.com/dl.php?v=YTo0OntzOjk6IndhdGVybWFyayI7YjowO3M6NzoidmlkZW9JZCI7czozMjoiYzc5YWZmNmIwYzkwNzk2ZDMxODg0YmU0MmMxMjJjNGIiO3M6MzoidWlkIjtzOjMyOiJlZDBiNGY4ZWFmZjJjMjllNjZiMzEzZjc0YTMxZWYzOCI7czo0OiJ0aW1lIjtpOjE2NDg5MTAxMjg7fQ==",
wm: "https://ttdownloader.com/dl.php?v=YTo0OntzOjk6IndhdGVybWFyayI7YjoxO3M6NzoidmlkZW9JZCI7czozMjoiYzc5YWZmNmIwYzkwNzk2ZDMxODg0YmU0MmMxMjJjNGIiO3M6MzoidWlkIjtzOjMyOiJlZDBiNGY4ZWFmZjJjMjllNjZiMzEzZjc0YTMxZWYzOCI7czo0OiJ0aW1lIjtpOjE2NDg5MTAxMjg7fQ==",
audio: "https://ttdownloader.com/mp3.php?v=YTozOntzOjc6InZpZGVvSWQiO3M6MzI6ImM3OWFmZjZiMGM5MDc5NmQzMTg4NGJlNDJjMTIyYzRiIjtzOjM6InVpZCI7czozMjoiZWQwYjRmOGVhZmYyYzI5ZTY2YjMxM2Y3NGEzMWVmMzgiO3M6NDoidGltZSI7aToxNjQ4OTEwMTI4O30="
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you figure out a solution?